# Run external program with custom argumets

Tags: java, textfield, external-process

I am trying to run an external program with custom arguments placed in text field.

Here is my code:

```
String customPARAM = textfield.getText();
try {
    new ProcessBuilder("MyEXE.exe", "-param1 " + customPARAM).start();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

The problem is that the output doesn't take my `customPARAM` and it does something like `MyEXE.exe -param1`.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: PS: output should be MyEXE.exe -param1 customPARAM

Comment: The thing is the output desn't take my customPARAM and the output is something like MyEXE.exe -param1

Comment: Try changing `"-param1 "+customPARAM)` to `"-param1 ", customPARAM)`

Comment: Can't do that i got already 2 parameters and i need to assign new value to process if i do that

Comment: @Kimmyshor Welcome to Stackoverflow! That said, it is important to read through the ["how to ask a good question"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article, and edit your post accordingly. As it stands, you have not actually asked a question yet, so it's a good idea to read through that, and then edit your post to hit the requirements outlined in the  article.

Comment: You need to be more precise about why you don't want to separate all your parameters with comma. What you are saying now doesn't clarify anything (at least for me).

Comment: So try to explain how does content of `customPARAM` look like, what command based on it you want to create, and what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: the customPARAM it is for a new session of that program and looks like -new_session %RANDOM%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a **whitespace** separate arguments with '**`,`**':

```
new ProcessBuilder("MyEXE.exe", "-param1 ", customPARAM, ...).start();
```

See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html): `ProcessBuilder(String... command)`.